# Efeito de palavras aleatorias

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Pessoal estou querendo uma informação eu estou atras de um efeito cujo o nome eu não sei estou tentando procurar na internet porem como não sei o nome fica bem difícil e ainda por cima não tenho uma referencia por isso vou explicar oque é mais ou menos seria isso :

Eu possuo uma palavra e a partir dela outras se formam um exemplo que eu vi era algo assim havia a palavra e as letras começavam a cair uma a uma e iam aparecendo novas letras formando outra palavra isso provavelmente e feito com Jquery porem estou pesquisando e não encontro por não saber qual o nome desse efeito não sei se e alguma API ou algo similar poderiam me ajudar.

Comment: Tipo os serviços de email que quando você digita um email que já existe ele sugere outros a partir daquele que você tentou?

Comment: Acredito que não seja exatamente isso que procura, mas achei bem legal... http://tympanus.net/Development/SlidingLetters/#

Comment: nao nao isso entraria no conceito de autocomplete e um efeito que fica repetindo infinitas veses tipo no codigo colocao N palavras e elas vao alternando entre elas sei que existe variados efeitos para fazer essa transição so nao sei como pesquisalos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formando texto novo, quer dizer? [Talvez esteja falando disto](http://kiro.me/projects/textualizer.html). É um plugin de jQuery que faz transição entre frases, basta colocar altura no elemento que contém o texto:

```js
var list = ['Textualizer is a jQuery plug-in that allows you to transition through blurbs of text. Just like this...'
          , 'When transitioning to a new blurb, any character that is common to the next blurb is kept on the screen, and moved to its new position.'
          , 'Textualize: verb - to put into text, set down as concrete and unchanging.  Use Textualizer to transition through blurbs of text.'
          , 'Blurb: noun - a short summary or some words of praise accompanying a creative work.  A promotional description.'];

var txt = $('#txtlzr');

txt.textualizer(list, { duration: 3000 });
txt.textualizer('start');
```

```css
#txtlzr {
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/krisk/textualizer/master/textualizer.min.js"></script>

<div id="txtlzr"></div>
```